# Uniqueness validation unless part of a parent-child relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a project where I have a model called `transaction`. A `transaction` can have many child transactions, using the key `parent_transaction_id`. The parent-child relationship can only be one layer deep, so a child can't have it's own child.

A `transaction` also has an attribute called `reference_number` I'd like this attribute to be unique, apart from within the parent-child relationship. So a parent and child can have the same `reference_number`, but two unrelated transactions can't. I currently have:

`validate :reference_number, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true`

I originally thought to have an `unless: -> { is_parent_child }` condition on the validation, but it doesn't seem to be possible to do what I want with this method.

Any help with finding a way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you allow the child reference number to be different from the parent's reference number?

Comment: No, if a transaction has a parent, they must have the same reference number

Comment: Then you don't really need to store reference number on the child model. You can make your own accessor  `def reference; return parent_transaction&.reference if parent_transaction&.reference; self[:reference];end`  This will return the reference of the parent, and if there's no parent it'll return the reference of the current transaction.

Comment: That's a great idea, thank-you!

Comment: Sorry I've come across an issue with this, it seems like now the children fail 
 the uniqueness validation because they return their parents reference? How do I prevent this?

Comment: You can do `validates :reference_number, uniqueness: true, if: 'parent_transaction_id.blank?'` and have a `before_validation :reset_reference_number`     and `def reset_reference_number; self.reference_number = nil if parent_transaction_id.present?; end`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which is to write custom validation like below:

```
validate :reference_number_uniq

def reference_number_uniq
  if self.reference_number && self.exists?('id != ? AND reference_number = ?', 
    self.child_transaction_id, 
    self.reference_number)
    errors.add(:reference_number, "is not valid")
  end
end
```

Using `unless` may work, but it may need to perform one more query before validate uniqueness of reference_number.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid having to write my own uniqueness validation, I thought there may be something like an inverse of scope, where it allows duplication if the id is the same, but it looks like there isn't.

Comment: Yep. Built-in validation is for common case, in your case, I think that you should write a custom one.

Comment: Did you mean `self.class.exists?`  and it will fail when you're saving an existing record and it will fail when you save the child, not the parent

Comment: Yep, you are correct. The query is incorrect as you pointed out, but I don't think that the author need it anymore. So I won't update it, will think more about this later.